# Dynamically add values to specific property in object - Fluent UI React ContextualMenu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, spfx

I have the following **ContextualMenu** structure inside my SPFx Extension build with Fluent UI React:

```
const menuProps: IContextualMenuProps = {
  items: [
    {
      key: 'Access',
      itemType: ContextualMenuItemType.Section,
      sectionProps: {
        topDivider: true,
        bottomDivider: true,
        title: 'Sites you have access to',
        items: [
          { key: 'DynamicValue1.1', text: 'DynamicValue1.2' },
          { key: 'DynamicValue2.1', text: 'DynamicValue2.2' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I also a MS Graph call running getting me some SharePoint Sites & Teams.

I would now like to push those dynamic responses to the to the `menuProps` at the right place.

So basically add the dynamic array into the nested `items` object.

```
items: [
          { key: 'DynamicValue1.1', text: 'DynamicValue1.2' },
          { key: 'DynamicValue2.1', text: 'DynamicValue2.2' },
        ],
```

How can I target that "object"? *(hope I understand correctly and `items` is an object...)*

Is there a way to do this using `array.push()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this library agnostic, it would look something like this:

```
 const obj = {
  items: [
    {
      key: 'Access',
      itemType: '',
      sectionProps: {
        topDivider: true,
        bottomDivider: true,
        title: 'Sites you have access to',
        items: [
          { key: 'DynamicValue1.1', text: 'DynamicValue1.2' },
          { key: 'DynamicValue2.1', text: 'DynamicValue2.2' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};


obj.items[0].sectionProps.items.push({ key: 'DynamicValue3.1', text: 'DynamicValue3.2' })

console.log(obj.items[0].sectionProps.items)
```

Your `console.log` would return this:

```
[
  { key: 'DynamicValue1.1', text: 'DynamicValue1.2' },
  { key: 'DynamicValue2.1', text: 'DynamicValue2.2' },
  { key: 'DynamicValue3.1', text: 'DynamicValue3.2' }
]
```

If you can access `menuProps: IContextualMenuProps`, then just replace `obj` with the necessary variable.

Comment: I was able to use the `menuProps` variable and insert the dynamic values. Thank you so much @AttemptedMastery !

Comment: Not a problem!  I am glad it helped!